# text editor reloads when saving over samba

Tags: windows, samba, ubuntu, redhat, server-message-block

We've been running Red-hat Enterprise Linux 4.0, for in house web development work for a year.
The basic setup is a shared folder (www) over samba that we use to access our web files.

When our licence expired for Redhat, we decided to go to a free alternative (Ubuntu 9.04).

However we have experienced an annoying problem, with saving files over samba. After saving the text editor asks to reload the file, as if someone else had changed it just after our original save.  We never had this problem with Red-hat.

My guess is that when saving the last modified date changes, and causes the text editor to think it's been modified.

Any ideas?

** UPDATE ** 15:09
There are a couple of diffs between the smb.conf's

I've removed

; logs split per machine
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log

; max 50KB per log file, then rotate
max log size = 50

and
  encrypt passwords = yes
has changed to
  encrypt passwords = true

Redhat:
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 3.0.33
Release    : 3.7.el5

Ubuntu: 2:3.3.2-1ubuntu3.1

I was running RHEL5.1

** UPDATE ** 15:17 14/08/2009

I thought LOhit had the answer.

Turning off oplocks did stop the problem, it stopped us receiving notices that the file had been modified by someone else.

Comment: I've have uploaded my smb.conf to http://pastebin.com/f433ca66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did experience this problem with later versions of Ubuntu.

My guess there was a bug somewhere in Ubuntu 9.04 that caused our issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at the "oplocks" for that share....

Comment: did have oplocks = yes

changed to oplocks = no

Answer (score 0):

- Did you implement your old smb.conf
  to the new server?
- What verison of samba did you have
  installed on RH and now have on
  Ubuntu?
- Has this always been a problem or
  only recently since the distro
  change?
- side note: You might what to check out using SVN
  instead of SAMBA it does verison
  control and locking

Comment: Ideally I'd like people to use SVN to checkout files, however the users have gone for the simplicity of checking out to the samba share.

This share (www), is used with vhost in apache to simplify initial testing setup.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, and just for your reference, CentOS is Redhat Enterprise Linux compiled from source. RHEL is Open Source, it is just the support contracts that cost money.

[CentOS](http://www.centos.org)

Comment: Might have to consider CentOS if it offers later packages than Redhat.